# Interactive 3D Objects

Tags: objects

my question may sound too small.

I want to create or export the rendered object, for example a cube in such a format that, I will be able to interact or rotate it in the same manner I do it in the object mode in the blender.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try blender 2.8 for that.  But you must backup your files before try 2.8 because blender 2.8 is not stable, it could break your files. Blender 2.8 has EVEE which can render in real time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Ryo.  To be frank I have started learning Blender couple of days back and I have managed to save an object in static or in non interactive mode. Sure, I will use blender 2.8 as I am new and no projects to save.  Could you please share any link or document which guides my purpose? Tanks in advance

Comment: I'm new to blender too. And because English is not my language so i learn blender alot from youtube. May be you'll want to check out Guru's Channel his tutorials are good for beginer. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYj6e-72RDs

Comment: I appreciate your effects in trying to help.... Exactly I am watching his videos.  Will search more to find answer to my purpose..anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [Blend4Web WebGL solution](https://www.blend4web.com/en/). You may find it interesting. Using it you can make interactive 3d content that can be viewed in 3d in web browsers. You could bake a more complex lighting to textures using Cycles.